# ¿Como crear el efecto de inserción de un elemento en otro con css?

Tags: html, css

He investigado como replicar el efecto de la imagen que adjunto sin suerte, solo se como crear el efecto de circulo con bordes blancos dando un efecto muy parecido pero sin bordes redondeados como se muestra en el siguiente código:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px
}

.barra-negra {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #141414;
}

.circulo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="barra-negra">
    <div class="circulo"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es algo parecido a la imagen sin tener que utilizar borde blanco y con los bordes de la caja negra redondeados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que tendras que generar un `svg` con esa forma y luego poner el botón con `position: absolute;`

Comment: gracias investigare sobre eso ahora mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metiendo dos `<div>` más en la ecuación, y jugando con su `border-radius` podrías conseguir algo bastabte satisfactorio.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px
}

.contenedor-forma {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.barra-negra {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
}

.forma-circulo {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.barra-negra-inferior {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #141414;
}

.barra-negra-izq {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 31px;
  background-color: #141414;
  border-radius: 0 58px 0 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.barra-negra-der {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 31px;
  background-color: #141414;
  border-radius: 58px 0px 0 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.circulo {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -29px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor-forma">
    <div class="forma-circulo">
      <span class="circulo"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="barra-negra">
      <div class="barra-negra-izq"></div>
      <div class="barra-negra-der"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="barra-negra-inferior"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```